# Get name of a month name from the text strin in the cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to find a way to get the name of the month from text string in a google sheet. I have:

`enter date is November 5th 2022`

and I need to get in the cell `November` as result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(?i)"&JOIN("|",INDEX(UNIQUE(TEXT(SEQUENCE(365,1,DATE(2022,1,1),1),"\\b"&"MMMM"&"\\b")))))`

-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is string then use-

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1, " "),1,1)
```

And if it is true date, formatted as desired then use below formula to extract month as full name.

```
=TEXT(A1,"mmmm")
```

[image]

Comment: it wont work, a have text such as "enter date is November 5th 2022" and " date is May 15th 2022". The text in the string doest in the same order, but i need to get name of month from it

Comment: @ЕленаЖелевская Then try this one `=INDEX(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"enter date is ",""), " "),1,1)`.

Comment: is there any chance thet i could find name of the  month, because my column does not have the same order of worsd in each cell. Sometimes it is "enter date is November 5th 2022" and sometimes it "November 5th 2022" and sometimes "date is May 15th 2022". And your formula does not work for such tipes

Comment: @ЕленаЖелевская I think you have to explore `REGEXEXTRACK()` function then. Post more sample data to your post as text table.

Comment: i try, but it works onle for date (REGEXEXTRACT(E7;"\d+")), for name of month it does not work